# Using conditional types to extract returned value type

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-types

I'm trying to figure out how conditional types work but it seems I'm not understanding something correctly.

Let's say I have an API that returns some data in a specific format:

```js
type SchemaOne = {
    [key: string]: {
        schemaOnePropOne: string;
        schemaOnePropTwo: string;
    };
}

type SchemaTwo = {
    [key: string]: {
        schemaTwoPropOne: string;
        schemaTwoPropTwo: string;
    };
}
```

and I need to transform them to this format:

```js
type TransformedSchemaOne = {
    title: string;
    schemaOnePropOne: string;
    schemaOnePropTwo: string;
}
type TransformedSchemaTwo = {
    title: string;
    schemaTwoPropOne: string;
    schemaTwoPropTwo: string;
}
```

So I can use a function like so:

```js
const transformSchemas = <T extends Schemas>(obj: T): ExtractReturnedType<T>[] => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    const newObj = keys.map(key=> ({title: key, ...obj[key]}))
    return newObj;
}
```

which would give me

> [{
> "title": "title",
> "schemaOnePropOne": "one",
> "schemaOnePropTwo": "two"
> }]

Now I want to introduce types to that function so I created a union of the schemas from one API

```js
type Schemas = SchemaOne | SchemaTwo;
```

and a conditional type to extract the return value:

```js
type ExtractReturnedType<S> = S extends SchemaOne ? TransformedSchemaOne : S extends SchemaTwo ? TransformedSchemaTwo : never;
```

this seems to work when I test with a specific schema:

```js
// no type errors 
const testOne:ExtractReturnedType<SchemaOne>[] = [{
    schemaOnePropOne: 'string;',
    schemaOnePropTwo: 'string;',
    title: 'string;',
}]
// no type errors
const testTwo:ExtractReturnedType<SchemaTwo>[] = [{
    schemaTwoPropOne: 'string;',
    schemaTwoPropTwo: 'string;',
    title: 'string;',
}]
```

But when I create the typed function I get typerrors:

```js
const transformSchemas = <T extends Schemas>(obj: T): ExtractReturnedType<T>[] => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    const newObj = keys.map(key=> ({title: key, ...obj[key]}))

    // Type '({ schemaOnePropOne: string; schemaOnePropTwo: string; title: string; } | { schemaTwoPropOne: string; schemaTwoPropTwo: string; title: string; })[]' is not assignable to type 'ExtractReturnedType<T>[]'.
    // Type '{ schemaOnePropOne: string; schemaOnePropTwo: string; title: string; } | { schemaTwoPropOne: string; schemaTwoPropTwo: string; title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ExtractReturnedType<T>'.
    // Type '{ schemaOnePropOne: string; schemaOnePropTwo: string; title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ExtractReturnedType<T>'.(2322)
    return newObj;
}
```

[Link to playground with code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIYHkB20C8UDeAUFCVANoDWEIAXFAM7ABOAlpgOYC6dRpfDiFBmwAFJgHswWCHUasOAbmL8S9QWmljJAFQDu42czbslfAL5KzhQqEhRtTVJnoAzcU2QQAJvCQbsUHi8pMAswAA2MgxGisqq6sIQWlLYhvImcQJ+icl6BtHplta20L5CeYEEmZTUacbcVSrx2XnJ0nWxTVnl+rn6HRnmRTbg0A5Oru6ePgkVQZmhEVFyxqakai29EinLMYPrs1s6-QWrhFYjdmVo9JXXiVAAPrCH4kqX0ACiAB7MqHDAABKEGAAFcmNgvNpRgAeGAAPjuUAgvwgmC8t3u0igAH57I5nG4PN4sQE6DBkaj0ZjXrj8RMidN7hU6NgAG4QJjvQhwcTOYBQYAQRjtH5-AHAsEQ7zQyBwhLSeFkTiVMjBZpCTTbdpQADkK0UuoANJkNprRNs8nR9XsFMaFmFItaDSZ7WZONZefzBcLgFaxY4JSDwZDZRB5ZtxEqVXg1abXm1UnqXXaTXwzWhWpaTjbCva+IsncnbW6PTy+YxBQTJh57vQAKqYEpeSoACnEACMAFZ0JwgACUgUR6qgXsrVBAtzw6G7EABADoJ-R293+2sSGOBdhdDOu5Ul-O0GBWxOcIjW-hC1EJ0aoPP752uzUQJwzP3+9Y+ExgxCoNvd8MY7iJE87hOI7Ctn8hJTHWjbNheV48BmOTakmup8hAxrdP4STZvkurAPoupmG+H7lt6UE1sgdaVDC2iUkK1IvNk9DwiuPb2P2dABv8QI-qGsLaNGQ6NKQm5QEulS7nOwCLtQy6PmumTif+3b7vJh6oMep7npejrXtQt73vOj7Pq+76fqQ35Spgf4QDu3bDNYhBAA)

Comment: Evaluation of conditional types that depend on unspecified generic type parameters is completely deferred by the compiler, so there's no way it can verify that `newObj` is assignable to it.  You can either use a type assertion and move on like [this](https://tsplay.dev/4w1oAm), or refactor your code to do things that the compiler does have a chance of understanding, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/PmL62w).  If that helps I can write it up as an answer... are you okay abandoning conditional types or do you want the "use a type assertion" answer?

Comment: The second solution seems to be what I'm looking for. I was under the impression that the parameter I was passing was not unspecified generic since I'm saying that `T extends Schemas`. In any case please write up the answer based on the second solution and I will accept is as correct. Thnx a lot for the help !

Comment: By "unspecified" I mean that it is not a specific type. `T` is *constrained* to some subtype of `Schemas` but it is not a *specific* subtype inside the implementation of `transformSchemas()`.  When you *call* `transformSchemas()`, the value for `T` becomes specified with a specific type either written out manually or inferred by the compiler.

Comment: I think I found a better solution, `const transformSchemas = (obj: Schemas ): ExtractReturnedType<Schemas>[]` seems to work and the return object keeps the correct type  [Playground Link](http://shorturl.at/vwN07)